# ARcore compatible device list

Tags: android, arcore

I have a Samsung sm-p205 tablet, which is not in the ARcore supported device list
My question is if it is possible to add this tablet so I can install ARcore, if not possible why. Below the specs
Thank you

DISPLAY Type    IPS LCD
Size    8.0 inches, 185.6 cm2 (~75.2% screen-to-body ratio)
Resolution  1200 x 1920 pixels, 16:10 ratio (~283 ppi density)

PLATFORM    Android 11, One UI Core 3.1
Chipset Exynos 7904 (14 nm)
CPU Octa-core (2x1.8 GHz Cortex-A73 & 6x1.6 GHz Cortex-A53)
GPU Mali-G71 MP2

MEMORY  Card slot   microSDXC (dedicated slot)
Internal    32GB 3GB RAM
eMMC 5.1

MAIN CAMERA Single  8 MP, f/2.0, AF
Features    LED flash, panorama
Video   1080p@30fps
SELFIE CAMERA   Single  5 MP, f/2.2
Video   1080p@30fps

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if other Methods work without rooting your device, or at least they have never worked for me. After a quick Google search I am able to find some repos/articles that might be right for you:

https://github.com/tomthecarrot/arcore-for-all

https://arpost.co/2020/08/18/how-to-enable-arcore-on-any-android-device/

Please read the whole Disclaimer CAREFULLY before continuing:

Do some Research before doing this please. Only try this if the previous Method did not work. If you do banking or stock trading (or anything money related tbh), most providers will disable their apps while your device is rooted. If you are not tech savvy, it may pose a significant security Risk for your Device, so be wary. There is also the risk of bricking your device (making it unusable).

1. Root your Tablet: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/samsung-galaxy-tab-a-8-0-2019-with-s-pen-lte-sm-p205-root-achieved-howto.3971209/
2. Install this Magisk Module: https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/ARCore_enabler
3. You're done. Have fun.

Comment: Yes I saw that post, I don't want to root the device, it's strange to me that it's not listed, they have the Samsung galaxy j5 in the list way inferior